# Is there any way to call a function in JavaScript multiple times at once? Using puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, chromium, ethereum, puppeteer

A website is developed using Reactjs, which interacts with ethereum smart contract in the backend.

This smart contract requires one chrome extension (metamask) for transaction.

Now while using puppeteer it runs in the chromium where chrome extensions aren't available.

Also I wanna run this contract in parallel. That means it runs same contract multiple times at once in order to know how much time will it take to get the result when many users at once are using that website.

1. Is there any to way to load chrome extensions in puppeteer?
2. How to run that javascript file multiple times at once?

Comment: It's hard to say how you mean to run  `that javascript file multiple times` without checking the code itself or even a sample code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Loading Extensions

Discussed [here](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/659#issuecomment-341965254), You can use --disable-extensions-except to enable only the extensions that you want to test:

```
var options = {
  headless: false,
  args: [
    '--disable-extensions-except=/path/to/extension/',
    '--load-extension=/path/to/extension/',
  ]
}
```

For loading multiple chrome extensions, you can pass a comma-seperated list;

```
var options = {
  headless: false,
  args: [
    '--disable-extensions-except=/path/to/ext1/, /path/to/ext2/, /path/to/ext3/'
  ]
}
```

Note, it will not work in `headless` mode, nor you can automate the extensions themselves.

## Multiple times at once?

You can create multiple pages/tabs with same metamask, or create [different browser sessions](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.9.0/docs/api.md#class-browsercontext) to keep things seperate.

Comment: Multiple times at once, I meant:
for example, If multiple users try to book a ticket online, at that time what really happens in the backend is that a function is called once for each user at once.
something like that I wanna implement in javascript to check the loading time to get the results.

Comment: I cannot write the code for you if you don't share more information/code etc and ask more specific question. You are talking about load balancing, execution time and multiple sessions which will require a lot of writing to cover. So please try to code yourself and ask very specific question. Just like how I answered the question about chrome extensions above.

Comment: for extensions, you suggested to use --disable-extensions-except flag,
but still, it is unable to load. 
` args: [
        "--diable-extensions-except= /home/nish/.config/google-chrome/Default/Extensions/nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/4.13.0_0/"
      ],`
Do I have to specify any specific file in the path.?

Comment: did you try `/home/nish/.config/google-chrome/Default/Extensions/nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn` as path?

Comment: Yes i did. chromium was unable to load the extension